# I'm getting this error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." in my console

Tags: reactjs

## I'm getting this error in my console where it says "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." don't understand how to solve it

[This is my the image of the error I'm getting in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxouB.png)

## This Is the code i write for products component

```
const Products = ({ cat, filters, sort }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          cat
            ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products?category=${cat}`
            : "http://localhost:5000/api/products"
        );
        setProducts(res.data);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    getProducts();
  }, [cat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    cat &&
      setFilteredProducts(
        products.filter((item) =>
          Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
            item[key].includes(value)
          )
        )
      );
  }, [products, cat, filters]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sort === "newest") {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt)
      );
    } else if (sort === "asc") {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
      );
    } else {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
      );
    }
  }, [sort]);

  return (
    <Container>
      {cat
        ? filteredProducts.map((item) => <Product item={item} key={item.id} />)
        : products
            .slice(0, 8)
            .map((item) => <Product item={item} key={item.id} />)}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

## This is the code i write for product component

```
const Product = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Circle />
        <Image src={item.img} />
        <Info>
          <Icon>
            <ShoppingCartOutlined />
          </Icon>
          <Icon>
            <Link to={`/product/${item._id}`}>
            <SearchOutlined />
            </Link>
          </Icon>
          <Icon>
            <FavoriteBorderOutlined />
          </Icon>
        </Info>
      </Container>
    );
  };
```

## Don't understand the source of error also

Comment: I guess that it should be `item._id` and not `item.id`

Comment: thanks the error is solved now thank you for your time and knowledge

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check filteredProducts, maybe the id of the item in this array is null. or the same id exists

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer, or are you just asking for clarification from the OP? This reads like it should be a comment.